# Want to create a search engine for my android application for search local database which Technology should i use?

Tags: android

i want to create a search engine for my android application for search my local database

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH7jY.png]

Which Technology should i use like php or java or sqlite?
Please tell the answer in details
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? probably you are looking for [`AutoCompleteTextView.`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView)

Comment: This site works best with specific questions; this one is pretty broad. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask